# Have a MySQL Database, PHP Form isn't working, but connection is Successful

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I created a PHP form, and I would like to record the results to a database. When I test the connection file on its own it is successful. When I attempt to include the file with the connection instead, the form does not save the information? Am I missing a step here?

Updates: The first thing I had to discover was to use MYSQLi instead of MYSQL (Abandoned the PHP route a long time ago). So instead of compounding my issues, I am trying to troubleshoot the connection in one file first.

```
    <?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '*****', '*****', '******');


if($conn->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');


} else {
    echo "Have a good night!";
}


error_reporting(E_ALL);

$query = "SELECT id AS txt FROM `Pages`";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if($result === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    $result->data_seek(0);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['txt'] . '<br>';
    }  
}

$result->free();
$conn->close();

?>
```

This updated code now returns this error:
Have a good night!

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/******/public_html/file.php on line 18

Fatal error: Call to a member function data_seek() on a non-object in /home/*******/public_html/file.php on line 23

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: get_magic_quotes_gpc, addslashes,mysql. this code is dangerously outdated

Comment: Is this file the `dor.php` you are `POST`ing to? If so the `action` declaration is unnecessary. Also, `mysql_` has been deprecated in lieu of `mysqli_` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and/or `PDO` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Please check mysqli, you're creating something that's about to become obsolete. In your current code I see a mysql_select_db, but nowhere a mysql_connect. That might be the problem. But please check into mysqli and properly filter your form inputs on the server side (look for filter_input in PHP)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: If you are learning PHP for a production application consider learning an MVC framework such as Laravel, symfony, Yii, CodeIgniter and Zend.  It will help you access more secure libraries and ways of coding, without having to learn from scratch.  If on the other hand you want to learn from the ground up, you have started in the right place.  See @tadman's comment for the next step!

Comment: What is this in else part `$PTitle = $_POST['$PTitle'];`; it's `$PTitle` or `PTitle`;

Comment: @CaleW.Vernon where did you get dor.php? What line was that on?

Comment: @贝壳-BeiKe: From the `<form>`'s `action` property.

Comment: @Fred-ii- added additional error reporting

Comment: @Dagon removed outdated code.

Comment: @CaleW.Vernon update to more recent code, just trying to return results I added in mysql first now.

Comment: @patrick mysql_connect seems to go with PDO, not MySQLi? Correct?

Comment: @tadman I would be more interested in OOP. I checked the link, phptherightway, but I was confused as to where to go. I checked the interacting with databases section, but it was a bit oversimplified for me. Do I NEED all those model and view files as well? Looks more MVC stuff. Is that what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's worth looking at frameworks, they do considerably more out of the box than raw PHP can do. That PHP guide is mostly a list of best practices, especially when it comes to databases. Don't forget the PHP documentation on things like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is actually pretty good and the comments can be very helpful.

Comment: @tadman likely a good general resource, I'm sure I will return once I understand a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input type="submit" id="add" value="Save">` should have `name="add"`. Also, it is not good to use the old mysql interface. Use mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

please change this code with your code

```
 <?php

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', '*****', '*****', '******');

    if($conn->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
```

use `$conn` through out it shows, you use new variable `$db`

Comment: Check your database access credential.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the godaddy autogenerated password had an illegal char.